# Full screen iFrame load with ajax

Tags: javascript, iframe

Do you know any script which can help to achieve effect like on whis website: http://www.julianabicycles.com/

When you clik on any bike, you can see lightbox sizing effect, but most important is that it is fullscreen.

I tryed to achieve look alike effect with colorbox and similar scripts, but i cant find option for width and height 100%.

I also tryed to examine code of that website, but i consider myself newbie in js, so that's why i'm looking for your help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That site is using swipe.js. https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe
But, colorbox has a width parameter.  The 100% will be of the containing div, so make sure that is also 100%.  You might want to show what you've tried.

Comment: Okay about slider, but i dont need that one. I am interested in effect when u click on bikes under main slider. It's just like iframe is being loaded by some lightbox script, and then you have fullscreen site.